# How does Initial velocity effect braking distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

supposed we have a car that slams the brake to bring it to stop, how would doubling it's mass affect braking distance and how would halving its velocity affect it?

I used the equation  d=Vi^2/2×a

Comment: Try and search for the wikipedia page of "braking distance" which will give you the right answer. Please make sure you put some effort into solving your questions yourself.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).